# How do I reflect changes to the intensity values in the 3D Shepp Logan data visualization?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have been doing a self study on the 3D Logan Phantom developed by CG Koay and research group. A mathematica notebook from this group is available [here](https://sites.google.com/site/hispeedpackets/Home/shepplogan/SheppLogan3D.nb?attredirects=0&d=1). The codes present a 3D visualization of a slight variation of the original [Shepp Logan data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepp%E2%80%93Logan_phantom). While trying to make modifications to these codes according to my experiment, I discovered that the visualizations are the same no matter the intensity values I use. To explain what I am trying to do, I exported the Shepp Logan data used in the notebook and it is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zoimyb5m7qspkm/3D%20Shepp%20Logan2.xls?dl=0). In the last column (intensity values), my experiment produced a much smaller intensity values like between 0.000002 and -0.0000002. I made changes to the intensity column but the patterns and colours are just about the same with the data used by Koay. Therefore, I would be very grateful if anyone would kindly offer suggestions on (1) how I can have a visualization which is unique to the intensity values (2) having a coloured legend showing the magnitude of the intensity (possibly this will resolve most of the problem). Thank you!!

Comment: The colors are not determined by the `intensity` but rather by the position of the function in the list of functions given as an argument to `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, thank you for your kind clarification. I guess that is why I could not use "PlotLegends" with ParametricPlot3D. Do you think that is a way this challenge can be overcome programmatically? Or is it possible to get the job done with DensityPlot3D?

Comment: Use PlotStyle and use the specific Intensity as an argument to the corresponding style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The colors are not determined by the `intensity` but rather by the position of the function in the list of functions given as an argument to [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html). To make the colors correspond to the `intensity`(last column) use the option [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

rotz[Ω_] := {{Cos[Ω], -Sin[Ω], 
   0}, {Sin[Ω], Cos[Ω], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}
rotx[Ω_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 
   Cos[Ω], -Sin[Ω]}, {0, Sin[Ω], 
   Cos[Ω]}}
roty[Ω_] := {{Cos[Ω], 0, 
   Sin[Ω]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[Ω], 0, 
   Cos[Ω]}}
```

Note that [`Ellipsoid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ellipsoid.html) is the name of a built-in function. User-defined functions should start with lower case letters to avoid naming conflicts with built-in names (now or in the future).

```
ellipsoid[{x0_, y0_, z0_, a_, b_, c_, ϕ_, θ_, ψ_, ρ_}][ 
  tt_, pp_] := (rotz[ϕ].roty[θ].rotz[ψ]).{a Sin[tt] Cos[pp], 
    b Sin[tt] Sin[pp], c Cos[tt]} + {x0, y0, z0}

(*   x0, y0, z0, a, b, c, ϕ, θ, ψ, ρ  *)
ellipsoids =
  {{0, 0, 0, 0.69, 0.92, 0.9, 0, 0, 0, 2.0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0.6624, 0.874, 0.88, 0, 0, 0, -0.8},
   {-0.22, 0.0, -0.25, 0.41, 0.16, 0.21, 3/5 Pi, 0, 0, -0.2},
   {0.22, 0.0, -0.25, 0.31, 0.11, 0.22, 2/5 Pi, 0, 0, -0.2},
   {0, 0.35, -0.25, 0.21, 0.25, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.2},
   {0, 0.1, -0.25, 0.0460, 0.0460, 0.0460, 0, 0, 0, 0.2},
   {-0.08, -0.65, -0.25, 0.0460, 0.023, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.1},
   {0.06, -0.65, -0.25, 0.0460, 0.023, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0.1},
   {0.06, -0.105, 0.625, 0.0560, 0.040, 0.1, Pi/2, 0, 0, 0.2},
   {0.0, 0.1, 0.625, 0.0560, 0.056, 0.1, Pi/2, 0, 0, -0.2}};
```

The range of intensities is

```
{minInt, maxInt} = MinMax[ellipsoids[[All, -1]]]

(* {-0.8, 2.} *)
```

`color` function to handle gradients specified by either strings (e.g., `"TemperatureMap"`) or symbols (e.g., `Hue`):

```
color[gradient_, intensity_?NumericQ] :=
  If[StringQ[gradient], ColorData[gradient], gradient][
   Rescale[intensity, {minInt, maxInt}]];
```

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to select color gradients:

```
Manipulate[
 g1 = ParametricPlot3D[
   ellipsoid[#][tt, pp] & /@ ellipsoids[[3 ;; 10]] // Evaluate,
   {tt, 0, Pi}, {pp, 0, 2 Pi},
   Boxed -> False,
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   ViewPoint -> {0.25, -1.15, 0.75},
   Axes -> False,
   ImageSize -> 550,
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
   Mesh -> False,
   PlotStyle -> (color[colorGradient, #] & /@
      ellipsoids[[3 ;; 10, -1]])];
 g2 = ParametricPlot3D[
   ellipsoid[#][tt, pp] & /@ ellipsoids[[1 ;; 2]] // Evaluate,
   {tt, Pi/2 + Pi/32, Pi}, {pp, 0, 2 Pi},
   Boxed -> False,
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   ViewPoint -> {0.25, -1.15, 0.75},
   Mesh -> False,
   ImageSize -> 550,
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> (color[colorGradient, #] & /@
      ellipsoids[[1 ;; 2, -1]])];
 Legended[
  Legended[
   Show[g1, g2],
   Placed[
    SwatchLegend[(color[colorGradient, #] & /@
       ellipsoids[[All, -1]]), 
     Automatic],
    {0.8, 0.5}]],
  Placed[
   BarLegend[{colorGradient, {minInt, maxInt}},
    LegendLabel -> "Intensity"],
   {0.9, 0.5}]],
 {{colorGradient, Hue}, Join[{Hue, GrayLevel,
    Blend[{{0, Red}, {.2, Yellow}, {.3, Green}, {1, Blue}}, #] &},
   ColorData["Gradients"]]}]
```

[image]

However, changing the intensities won't change the colors if the relative intensities remain the same. The intensities used in the `PlotStyle` are scaled to the range `{0, 1}` for any range of intensities.

Comment: I really appreciate your kind contribution. It has been brilliant. I have been trying several colorData in the past days and I can confirm LightTemperatureMap still gave the best results. However, when I added a legend, some of the legend colors are almost the same since their intensity values are very close. I tried using "Hue" but the code gave me errors for obvious reasons. I like to ask you if there is a way I can work around this. I am not sure it will give a better legend but it would be nice to try this out. Thanks.

Comment: you are wonderful! Many thanks.

Comment: Cleaned up code a bit.

Comment: Yes! It is very beautifully done. I really appreciate this. I have been suffering on this task for more than five months.

Comment: Thank you once again and also for this "However, changing the intensities won't change the colors if the relative intensities remain the same". In one of my datasets, the first two intensity values are significantly higher than the rest. Both are suppressing the contrasts from the other intensity values; I suppose this is due to the relative intensities remaining the same as you have noted. I was wondering if you could kindly offer a suggestion on a work around if it exists. I tied "ScalingFunctions ->"Log"" but not employable in parametric plots.

Comment: `colorGradient` includes an option which is tailorable, i.e., `Blend[{{0, Red}, {.2, Yellow}, {.3, Green}, {1, Blue}}, #] &`. By adjusting the points at which the colors change you can make a nonlinear color scale.